# NSURLConnection retry request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

How can i request a retry on a NSURLConnection? in my connectionDidFinishLoading method is it possible to store and later retry the connection?

i looked at [connection start], but that did not seem to do anything. Does the connection object still contain the original request?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's not stated explicitly, but still [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) suggests that `NSURLConnection` instance isn't intended to be reused:

*NSURLConnection retains its delegate when it is initialized. It releases the delegate when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled.*

If delegate is already released, there's really no point in reanimating connection object.

Comment: thanks Nikita, so what is the best way to retry a successful connection request?

Comment: @user609906 Create new a connection object. (you can reuse both request and delegate objects, if you don't let them to be released)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which is both MUCH easier to use than the built-in NSURLConnection business, but also much more featureful. You can specify the number of times to retry, the fail timeout, and basically every aspect of an HTTP request.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this thread: ASIHTTPRequest is no longer maintained. The developer suggests a number of alternatives such as AFNetworking.

Comment: Thanks, @lorean. I've recommended ASIHTTPRequest so many times in my posting history, I keep finding more places I have to go back and post updates with the deprecation announcement...

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by retaining the original `NSMutableURLRequest` object and creating the connection again, on Swift it looks something like this:

```
class MyConnectionHandler {
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest?
    var connection: NSURLConnection?
    var retryCount=0
    var maxRetries=2

    ...
    functions to setup the request object, and create a connection
    ----

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        if(retryCount<maxRetries) {
            retryCount++
            self.connection=NSURLConnection(request: request!, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        } else {
            <throw a tantrum>
        }
    }
```